# Is it possible for a declaration to escape its enclosing namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying to write a macro which assists in building an `enum class` with various helper functions, e.g. for conversion to string. It would be natural to provide access to **all values** of the enum in some kind of collection:

```
DEFINE_ENUM(Foo, Value1, Value2);

for (Foo v : enum_traits<Foo>::all_values) {
    // ...
}
```

It seems like this could be accomplished by making the `DEFINE_ENUM()` macro specialize a common `enum_traits` class:

```
// globally:
template<typename T> struct enum_traits {};

// inside the macro:
#define DEFINE_ENUM(Name, ...) \
    /* define "enum class Name" ... */ \
    template<> struct my_enum_traits<Name> { \
        /* define all_values member */ \
    };
```

However, if the expansion of `DEFINE_ENUM(Foo, Value1, Value2);` occurs inside a namespace, then it appears impossible for it to specialize a template from outside that namespace:

```
template<typename T> struct enum_traits {};

namespace foo {
    // imagine DEFINE_ENUM is invoked here:

    enum class Foo { Value1, Value2 };

    // error: class template specialization of 'enum_traits'
    //   must occur at global scope
    template<> struct ::enum_traits<Foo> { /* ... */ };
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this, i.e. for the macro to "escape" the namespace enclosing its invocation and specialize a template from a different namespace (even the global namespace)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I cannot directly help in this traits template specialization problem, I suspect this is not possible.

But it is possible to achieve your real goal with [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

See the trick:

```
// globally:
template<typename T> 
using enum_traits = decltype(get_enum_traits(T{}));
```

The trick is to define function `get_enum_traits` in namespace of `T`. This function shall have return type - the type that should be your traits. This function does not need an implementation - it is only ADL way to get type from within namespace of newly define enum type.

```
// inside the macro:
#define DEFINE_ENUM(Name, ...) \
    /* define "enum class Name" ... */ \
    enum class Name { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    struct Name##_type_traits { \  
       /* define all_values member */ \
    }; \  
    Name##_type_traits get_enum_traits(Name);
```

Some [demo](https://ideone.com/iwyTZm) that it really works.

```
#include <array>

// globally:
template<typename T> 
using enum_traits = decltype(get_enum_traits(T{}));

// inside the macro:
#define DEFINE_ENUM(Name, ...) \
    /* define "enum class Name" ... */ \
    enum class Name { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    struct Name##_type_traits { \
         static constexpr std::array<Name,1> values{{ Name{} }}; \
    }; \
    Name##_type_traits get_enum_traits(Name); // does not need implementation


namespace foo {
    DEFINE_ENUM(Foo, Value1, Value2);
}

int main( ) {
    for (auto e: enum_traits<foo::Foo>::values)
    {}
}
```

Comment: You could avoid the local class by defining, say, `struct Name ## Traits_` in the namespace and have `get_enum_traits(Name)` just return that.

Comment: @aschepler That's true.  Probably even better solution.

Comment: This seems to cause a linker error when you actually use `e` in the for loop http://cpp.sh/3glgj

Comment: @Drew this is because you use C++11 and constexpr  variable are not inline by default as in C++17. But this problem is is not related to OP question.